# NFS or SMB on Windows Share

Tags: nfs, smb, windows-share

If I were to create a Windows shared folder, put a database file in that folder to be shared among multiple users of our client app, is that an NFS or SMB shared folder?

Comment: Be careful as not all database formats support being read from a share.  Outlooks data format is  prime example of this

Comment: I'd like to place an sqlite database file on the share and access it from multiple clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record it is now supposed to be referred to as CIFS (Common Internet File System). But yes, it is SMB.

**Edit** apparently with Windows 8 and Server 2012 we're back to SMB with SMB 3. Thanks, BenL

Comment: windows8 and server 2012 will use smb 3.0

Answer (score 0):

That would be SMB.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is a SMB shared folder. The SMB (protocol) is the NFS (protocol) in the Windows world.

Comment: So it's by OS?  Are shares on UNIX/Linux/OSX NFS?

Comment: not by OS (not anymore, at least); but by mentality. also, there are very few good NFS implementations for windows.